# Can a general formula be developed for these integrals?

Tags: calculus, summation

Can the following integral $I$ be written wrt $n$?

$$I=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k}$$

I found the values for $n=1,2,3$ 
but can we generalize it for an arbitrary $n$?

Comment: Could you post your values for $n=1,2,3$?  That could save people some time.

Comment: For $n=2$ i got $I=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt {3}}$ (that's pretty easy). Next, for $n=3$ i got $I=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Do you know the identity $\sum_{k=0}^n x^k = (1-x^{k+1})/(1-x)$?
I think it might be helpfull here

Comment: It is always applicable for finite sums.

Comment: Ohh..what was i saying..

Comment: So the integral will become $I=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{x-1}{x^{n+1}-1}dx$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

$$I_{n+1}=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{\sum_{k=0}^{n} x^k}=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1-x}{1-x^{n+1}}dx$$

Mathematica 7.0 produces (after simplification) ($n>2$):

$$I_n=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\Gamma\left(1 - \frac1n\right)
     \Gamma\left(1 + \frac1n\right) - 
   (1/2)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\Gamma\left(1 - \frac2n\right)
     \Gamma\left(1 + \frac2n\right)$$

EDIT

This expression can be further simplified as pointed out by David H. and Lucian in the comments.

The Euler's reflection formula for the Γ function is given by:

$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}......(1)$$

We also have
$$\Gamma(1+z)=z\Gamma(z)......(2)$$

From (1) and (2) we obtain

$$\Gamma(1+z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi z}{\sin(\pi z)}......(3)$$

Substitution of (3) into the expression for $I_n$ leads to the neat expression:

$$I_n=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\frac{\pi/n}{\sin(\pi/n)} - 
   (1/2)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\frac{2\pi/n}{\sin(2\pi/n)}=\frac{\pi}{n}\csc{\frac{2\pi}{n}}$$

Comment: This is really amazing ! I wonder how a human being could make this ! Cheers :)

Comment: Note that this answer simplifies to $I_n=\frac{\pi}{n}\csc{\frac{2\pi}{n}}$, a very pleasing result indeed.

Comment: David's simplified result is obtained using [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties).